# Batch File Script to split a string into multiple subsisting in SSIS Execute Process Task

Tags: batch-file, ssis, executeprocesstask

I was trying to execute a batch file using SSIS execute process task. This task accepts only one argument. 
The argument is
@[User::TabProjectName]=**www.servername Dev_Admin Password123 DENMARK DEV V_Weekly_DEV**.This is a 
space-separated string.
How to split this single string into multiple substrings based on space and assigned to variables as shown below using **Batch command**?

```
set servername=www.servername
set username=Dev_Admin
set tabpwd=Password123
set sitename=DENMARK
set projectname=DEV
set datasourcename=V_Weekly_DEV
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: The argument contains spaces, so the usual course of action is to enclose the string in doublequotes. This would be received in a well written program as `%~1`, _which removes the enclosing doublequotes as a result of its expansion_, and passes as you had intended. The other thing you could consider is changing the program's `%1` argument to `%*` and seeing if your existing, _unquoted_, string works for you then.

Answer (score 1):

This was originally posted with a *powershell* tag, so this is how it can be done with powershell:

```
$string = '@[User::TabProjectName]=www.servername Dev_Admin Password123 DENMARK DEV V_Weekly_DEV'

$splitString = $string.split()

$serverName = $splitString[0].split('=')[1]
$username = $splitString[1]
$tabPwd = $splitString[2]
$siteName = $splitString[3]
$projectname = $splitString[4]
$datasourceName = $splitString[5]
```

$splitString, splits the initial string on spaces as no character is passed to the split operator.  Each item in the split array can be referenced by its place number.  The $serverName needs an additional split to get the data to the right of the '=' sign.

Comment: It shows there is no $splitString = $string.split().There is no split () in batch file !

Comment: @user1254579 - **_then WHY did you tag the Question with "powershell"?!?!?!?!?!?!?_** [*frown*]